# Hibernate OGM com MongoDB and JTA on Glassfish - javax.persistence.PersistenceException

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, jpa, jta, hibernate-ogm

Using Hibernate OGM, MongoDB and JTA on Glassfish 4.1. When a try to persist a get an error with this:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field br.com.juliocnsouza.mongojpaexemple.model.Developer.id to br.com.juliocnsouza.mongojpaexemple.model.Developer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After try everythig I found on the internet. The solution was stop using Hibernate OGM e try Eclipselink NoSQL. Just added a new dependency and changed some parts of my persistence xml and now its working just fine!

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/NoSQL

`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.nosql</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0-M3</version>
</dependency>`

simple exemple project: https://github.com/juliocnsouzadev/hibernateMongoDB/tree/master/OgmJpaMongodbEclipseLink

Comment: Sorry to hear about these troubles. Could you file an issue in the Hibernate OGM [issue tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/OGM), describing some more details (your entities, the code using them etc)? Then we can take a closer look and provide a fix in case there is a bug. Thanks!

Comment: Ok @Gunnar I'll do it. Thanks. :D